# Apache 2.4 Rasbery PI server requested url not found port 80

Tags: php, raspberry-pi, apache2.4

I am making a website using my raspberry pi with Apache 2.4, php5, and mysql. However, my website randomly stopped working. I went into phpMyadmin and created a database and it looks like after that it just flat out stopped working.

I believe the issue may be in the apache configuration since I can't even serve a simple php file.

PS. I am following a udemy course and used his exact code to test if it was my replicated code causing the problem. This didn't help. Also by putting a file called test.php and going [rasberypi IP addr]/test.php gave me the same issue not found.

Comment: can you show me the output of: `ls -all /var/www/html/`

Comment: Or can you pass in the content of your apache file logs (last few lines)